# Writing a condition logics in kotlin in a better way in kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, conditional-statements

I have a following condition logic and want to make it simple, is there a way to make it better without too much || && ? Some sample or example will be lovely! I would love to hear from you!

Logic that I want to achieve

From 0:00 on and 3 days before the birth month,
condition is the birth month is once or January 31st and
the present is run every December 29-31

```
   val birthYear = child.birthYear!!.toInt()
    val birthMonth = child.birthMonth!!.toInt()
    val date = DateTime()
    val year = date.year
    val month = date.month
    val day = date.day
    val maxDayOfMonth = date.maxDayOfMonth

class DateTime {
    private var mCalendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().also { it.clear() }

    val year: Int
        get() = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)。。。。。
```

The following is the logic that I want to make it simpler

```
return date.year > child.birthYear!!.toInt() &&
((birthMonth == 1 && month == 12 || birthMonth - 1 == month)
&& day >= maxDayOfMonth - 2 || birthMonth == month)
```

Comment: Your requirement is incomprehensible to me, but I hope you know that the AND logical operator `&&` has higher precedence than the OR operator `||`, so when you write: `birthMonth == 1 && month == 12 || birthMonth - 1 == month` it is equivalent to: `(birthMonth == 1 && month == 12) || birthMonth - 1 == month`.

Comment: Which type do you use for `date`?